# npm not installing packages and not creating package-lock.json

Tags: node.js, laravel, npm, npm-install, package.json

1. I created a new Laravel project with `laravel new x`
2. changed into that folder with `cd x`
3. tried installing the npm packages with `npm install`
4. This didn't work like expected.
5. I just got an Error: `Cannot destructure property 'name' of '.for' as it is undefined.`
6. Then I was like yeah lets just add a name to the package so I did
7. Ran `npm install` again
8. After that it installed something and prompted: `Installed 1 Package`
9. Instead of installing the specified `devDependencies`, creating a package-lock and a node_modules folder, it installed a package with the name that i just specified, globally. I knew that because of `npm ls -g`. So now i dont have any packages installed locally in my folder but a dependency globally that does nothing.

Output of `npm ls` and `npm ls -g`:

```
C:\Users\johnw\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── theNameIJustSpecified@
```

My `package.json` looks like this (and was auto-generated by the laravel installer):

```json
{
    "name": "myName",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "vite",
        "build": "vite build"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "axios": "^1.1.2",
        "laravel-vite-plugin": "^0.7.2",
        "lodash": "^4.17.19",
        "postcss": "^8.1.14",
        "vite": "^4.0.0"
    }
}
```

- npm -v: 9.2.0
- node -v: v19.3.0
- os: windows 11

Normally  this just worked out of the box with the Laravel installer. I just typed `npm install` and it worked.

I tried reinstalling Node and npm, even used Nvm for Windows without any change.
I tried restarting my pc without any change.
I tried creating the `package.json` via `npm init`, didn't change anything other than the output of `npm ls -g` (added 1.0.0 to the end):

```
C:\Users\johnw\AppData\Roaming\npm
└── theNameIJustSpecified@1.0.0
```

Edit: Tried downgrading to npm 8, also didn't work.
Downgrading to 7 works again, but I get warning because of too old version.

I checked other projects (old Laravel projects) and they have the same problem now. I used to work in them for months using npm packages for asset bundling. Now they give me the same error.

Comment: I am very curious if NPM 9.0+ is an issue or not, should not, but I have never saw this error before

Comment: I think you're missing a step in your description, what happened between step 6 and 7? You just re-ran `npm install` again?

Comment: try adding a `name` field the package.json as the npm spec states it is required

Comment: @ZackNewsham exactly, i reran `npm install` after adding a name

Comment: @BenGooding Thats what I've done, just how I described it. The problem from the title is still relevant.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Well, it was like this: I am a very frequent user of npm as a laravel developer, it is mostly used for vite and asset bundling so i normally use it all the time without problems. Now this morning npm recommended to upgrade to 9.2.0 and after the update i had those problems.

Comment: @Laisender there is either an "incompatibility" with how Laravel uses it (I also used it since Laravel 5.8 until 9x), or 9.2.0 has a known bug... I would try reverting to a previous available version like 9.1.9 if it exists. else go back to 9.0 or if you had 9.0.x or 9.1.x, go back to that version and try again